# MinGW как скомпилировать проект с несколькими cpp файлами

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, mingw, sfml, imgui

Пишу в vscode, я сделал рабочий проект с sfml, и хочу добавить в него ImGui по вот [этому гайду](https://habr.com/ru/post/335512/).
Но когда я пытаюсь скомпилировать проект через Makefile получаю много ошибок линковки.
Для начала я хочу убрать все ошибки линковки ImGui, а потом подключу glfw.

Вот мой код из Makefile:

```
all: compile link clean
compile:
    gcc -Isrc/include -Isrc/include/imgui -Isrc/include/imgui/imgui-sfml-master -c *.cpp -std=c++17
link:
    gcc *.o -o main -Lsrc/lib -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system       --subsystem,windows
clean:
    del *.o
```

[image: Мой проект]

Comment: *"получаю много ошибок линковки"* - каких?

Comment: imgui_demo.o:imgui_demo.cpp:(.text+0x17dfc): undefined reference to `ImGui::Separator()' и для других функций

Comment: это не удивительно, ведь imgui нигде не линкуется

Comment: ну так и как же мне его залинковать? я для этого вопрос и задал